# efficient way to divide ignoring rest

Tags: c++, division, modulus, floor

there are 2 ways i found to get a whole number from a division in c++

question is which way is more efficient (more speedy)

first way:

```
Quotient = value1 / value2;  // normal division haveing splitted number

floor(Quotient);             // rounding the number down to the first integer
```

second way:

```
Rest = value1 % value2;             // getting the Rest with modulus % operator

Quotient = (value1-Rest) / value2;  // substracting the Rest so the division will match
```

also please demonstrate how to find out which method is faster

Comment: There is also a [div](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/div/) function to get both (Quotient and Remainder). Because the processor has one cpu instruction to getting both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're dealing with integers, then the usual way is

```
Quotient = value1 / value2;
```

That's it. The result is already an integer. No need to use the `floor(Quotient);` statement. It has no effect anyway. You would want to use `Quotient = floor(Quotient);` if it was needed.

If you have floating point numbers, then the second method won't work at all, as `%` is only defined for integers. But what does it mean to get a whole number from a division of real numbers? What integer do you get when you divide 8.5 by 3.2? Does it ever make sense to ask this question?

As a side note, the thing you call 'Rest' is normally called <s>'reminder'.</s>remainder.

Comment: yep... a typo, sorry. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

Use this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef DIV_BY_DIV
#define DIV(a, b) ((a) / (b))
#else
#define DIV(a, b) (((a) - ((a) % (b))) / (b))
#endif

#ifndef ITERS
#define ITERS 1000
#endif

int main()
{
    int i, a, b;

    srand(time(NULL));
    a = rand();
    b = rand();

    for (i = 0; i < ITERS; i++)
        a = DIV(a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

You can time execution

```
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=1000000 -DDIV_BY_DIV 1.c && time ./a.out 

real    0m0.010s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=1000000 1.c && time ./a.out 

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Or, you look at the assembly output:

```
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=1000000 -DDIV_BY_DIV 1.c -S; mv 1.s 1_div.s 
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=1000000 1.c -S; mv 1.s 1_modulus.s 
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ diff 1_div.s 1_modulus.s 
24a25,32
>   movl    %edx, %eax
>   movl    24(%esp), %edx
>   movl    %edx, %ecx
>   subl    %eax, %ecx
>   movl    %ecx, %eax
>   movl    %eax, %edx
>   sarl    $31, %edx
>   idivl   20(%esp)
```

As you see, doing only the division is faster.

Edited to fix error in code, formatting and wrong diff.

More edit (explaining the assembly diff): In the second case, when doing the modulus first, the assembly shows that two `idivl` operations are needed: one to get the result of `%` and one for the actual division. The above diff shows the subtraction and the second division, as the first one is exactly the same in both codes.

Edit: more relevant timing information:

```
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=42000000 -DDIV_BY_DIV 1.c && time ./a.out 

real    0m0.384s
user    0m0.360s
sys     0m0.004s
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=42000000 1.c && time ./a.out 

real    0m0.706s
user    0m0.696s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Hope it helps.

Edit: diff between assembly with `-O0` and without.

```
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=1000000 1.c -S -O0; mv 1.s O0.s
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -DITERS=1000000 1.c -S; mv 1.s noO.s
mihai@keldon:/tmp$ diff noO.s O0.s
```

Since the defualt optimization level of `gcc` is `O0` (see [this article explaining optimization levels in `gcc`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7269)) the result was expected.

Edit: if you compile with `-O3` as one of the comments suggested you'll get the same assembly, at that level of optimization, both alternatives are the same.

Comment: No, no, it doesn't help. Any compiler optimizations will strip the whole thing, showing that you didn't compile with them on, that's horrific code, and you need to profile *real* usage, not a synthetic benchmark. This is a terrible idea, terrible execution. I downvoted you.

Comment: Nothing was stripped. If you want, I'll post the full assembly output for you to see that no optimization has broken the code. Also, the OP asked for a way to test this. If you have a better benchmark why don't you share it instead?

Comment: In general, writing decent benchmarks is actually quite hard; and also, in general, you don't have to be able to write a decent benchmark to be able to spot a horrible one when you see it.

Comment: Then please tell me why is this horrible? I'll learn to write a better one next time :)

Comment: O0 optimization benchmarks are worthless. Results are only even vaguely useful with the maximum compiler optimizations turned on, because, well, that's how real people compile their programs. You should only ever do benchmarks with the absolute maximum compiler optimization allowed. In addition, even if one is twice as slow, you'd also have to show that it is meaningfully slower when part of a real program. Oh, and hateful would be me telling you that you're bad. I only said your code was bad. Oh, and the question is C++, not C, so I'm also hating on your use of #define and such.

Comment: @DeadMG - OP asked for a benchmark, answer gave it. Code can be cut and pasted and used for benchmarking. Optimizations can be turned on/off by OP. And if it didn't matter in a real program, OP would not have asked. You might not see how it can; I can think of examples right away. But even after 30 years of programming sometimes I can't see it out of cotext and am suprised. Also, downvoting means 'answer is not useful' - see the tooltip over the down arrow. Does not apply to this answer. I cancelled your downvote.